# View Frustum Culling для AABB или Параллелепипед и усеченная пирамида

Tags: webgl, геометрия

Даны в трехмерном пространстве усеченная пирамида и параллелепипед.
Известны координаты вершин каждого объекта.
Как проверить, находится параллелепипед в усеченной пирамиде, пересекает ли ее, или находится вне ее?

Примерно так обобщена задача frustum culling, лишь отличие в том, что мне известны только такие вещи:
координаты вершин
Если догадались, то усеченная пирамида играет роль зоны видимости камеры, а параллелепипеды - boundingbox'ы объектов, которые нужно проверить на видимость для камеры

нашел вот такой документ, но пока не осилил его 
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.2.1491&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: Видимость камеры — не особо пирамида, т. к. простирается вдаль неограниченно. Я могу сделать ответ с точки зрения обозначенного приложения, **если вопрос ещё актуален**, т. к. заниматься этим просто так мне лениво.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi Видимость камеры – почти всегда усеченная пирамида, т.к. мы задаем плоскости ближнего/дальнего отсечения, чтобы у нас был вменяемый диапазон значений глубины.